# Dagger 2 does not generate file correctly in Android Studio

Tags: android, dagger-2

In my Android app I have a trouble with Dagger 2. I have a module that contains 3 dependencies, two of them are injected in activity but not the third one.

```
@Module
class MyNumberWriterModule(_type: Boolean) {
    private val type = _type
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideSimpleNumberWriter(): SimpleNumberWriter {
        return if (type) BelgianSimpleNumberWriter() else FrenchSimpleNumberWriter()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideIntegerNumberWriter(simpleNumberWriter: SimpleNumberWriter): IntWriter {
        return IntegerNumberWriter(simpleNumberWriter)
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideDecimalNumberWriter(intWriter: IntWriter): NumberWriter {
        return DoubleNumberWriter(intWriter)
    }
}
```

And here is a component

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [(MyNumberWriterModule::class)])
internal interface MyNumberWriterComponent {
    fun inject(mainActivity: MainActivity)
    // fun inject(baseActivity: _BaseActivity)
}
```

My activity

```
class MainActivity : _BaseActivity() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var numberWriter: IntWriter

    @Inject
    lateinit var numberWriter2: NumberWriter

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        DaggerMyNumberWriterComponent.builder()
                .myNumberWriterModule(MyNumberWriterModule(true))
                .build()
                .inject(this)
        // Here numberWriter is injected
        // Here numberWriter2 is NOT injected
    }
}
```

Any ideas why the third `@Provides` cannot be injected? I don't see any error messages but in the module Android Studio shows that `provideDecimalNumberWriter` is never used. There are no errors when I run the project

Comment: Code looks good to me, so I'd guess it's working as intended (maybe the lint does not take the generated code into account correctly). I encourage you to look at the generated code and see what Dagger injects when calling `.inject()` (e.g. ctrl+click on numberWriter2 usages and find the assignment from the Dagger component), or attach a debugger and verify what gets injected from where

Answer (score 0):

After a hours of experiments I created my class that I'm injecting `DoubleNumberWriter` and interface `NumberWriter` that implements my business logic in the package with another name and it started to work. Maybe dagger didn't like previous package name `double`